# If Cell is Empty Copy Cell Above

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub MacroFillAreas()

    For Each area In Columns("B:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If area.Cells.Row <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
            area.Cells = Range(area.Address).Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next area
End Sub
```

This is my macro for filling blank cells in my workbook. I am throwing an object error on `area.Cells = Range(area.Address).Offset(-1, 0).Value`

Can anyone explain why this happens? Here is a quick example of the data and what I am trying to do with it.

```
A  1  12
A  1  12
A  
A  
A  2  14
A  
A  3  14
A
A
```

That has to copy down the cells above:

```
A  1  12 
A  1  12
A  1  12
A  1  12
A  2  14
A  2  14
A  3  14
A  3  14
A  3  14
```

Comment: works as is for me. Are you running it from the same sheet you want to run it on? If another sheet is the active sheet it may through an error.

Comment: Furthering @Scott's comment - qualify the ranges with the sheet you expect them to be on.  But, I also get your error when running as is.

Comment: Also, is the very first row blank? I get the error if my row 1 is blank, since there is no `-1 row offset`.  Actually, I think you just need to put it in the worksheet module you plan to run this on. It works for me as is when doing so (as Scott pointed out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BruceWayneis right you'll get the error when B1:C1 are blank.

- Range objects of non-continuous cells have multiple areas. For this reason you should rename area to cell for clarification.
- area.Cells is misleading area is just 1 cell use area
- area is a range no need for this `Range(area.Address).Offset(-1, 0).Value` use `area.Offset(-1, 0).Value instead
- SpecialCells will throw an error if no cells are found.  You need to trap this error.

```
Sub MacroFillAreas()

    Dim cell As Range, SearchRange As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set SearchRange = Columns("B:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not SearchRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In SearchRange

            If cell.Row > 1 Then cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value

        Next cell
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yep! Just figured that out too, then looked back at this post and there you were with the same logic! :D